# Does the zombie preview screen give any clues as to which lanes the zombies will appear on?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

In Plants vs Zombies, at the beginning of every level you're given a preview of which zombies occur in that level while you select your plants. Is the arrangement of zombies on that screen random, or does it correspond to the lanes in which the zombies are going to appear?

Comment: One thing that might help is not to build expensive plants until the first zombie appears.

Comment: @Mechko, I generally only build sunflowers until the first zombie appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distribution is random. Here are a few screenshots I just took from the iOS version, backing out to the main menu between each one:

[image: PvZ screenshot]
[image: Braaaaains.]
[image: Graaaagh.]

Comment: I know that it's different every time you play a level. The question is whether the arrangement reflects their position for that particular game. In your third screenshot, for example, is the Jack-in-the-Box Zombies is going to appear in one of the bottom two lanes?

Comment: @JSBangs I can say for certain that even though you see 1 Jack-in-the-Box that more than one can and usually does appear over the course of the level. At best, I suppose the one you see could correspond to the FIRST appearance, but even if that is true, it doesn't really change how you have to build, because you still have to defend against them everywhere, and more-so against whatever zombies happen to be appearing right now.

Comment: The preview *does* tell you which types of zombies will appear though.

Comment: I don't understand, how the screenshot of zombie spread randomness should prove, that their apperance on lanes can't be predicted.